# Invalid argument supplied for foreach() - Codeignitor

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting an error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" while trying to fetch 'id' column using foreach loop:
Codeignitor version: 3.0.1

Controller:

```
<?php

class Users extends CI_Controller {
    
    public function show(){
        
        $this->load->model('user_model');
        $result = $this->user_model->get_users();
        foreach($result as $object){
            echo $object->id;
         }
    }
}

?>
```

Model:

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {
    
    public function get_users(){
    $this->db->get('users');
    }
}


?>
```

As I checked table name and column names are correct.

Comment: Shouldn't `public function get_users()` return something to work with?

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {
    
    public function get_users(){
    $data=$this->db->get('users');
    return $data->result();
    }
}


?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can fetch by using either result() or result_array() in  model

**in your case**

```
public function get_users(){ // model
    $data=$this->db->get('users');
    return $data->result();
}

public function show(){ // controller
    
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $result = $this->user_model->get_users();
    foreach($result as $object){
        echo $object->id;
     }
}
```

The above method returns the query result as an array of objects, or an empty array on failure.

The below one method returns the query result as a pure array, or an empty array when no result is produced.

**you can also do this**

```
public function get_users(){ // model
    $data=$this->db->get('users');
    return $data->result_array();
}

public function show(){ // controller
    
    $this->load->model('user_model');
    $result = $this->user_model->get_users();
    foreach($result as $object){
        echo $object['id'];
     }
}
```

for more details [click here](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Answer (score 0):

**you need to return result() or result_array()**

```
<?php
  class User_model extends CI_Model {
    public function get_users(){
    $data=$this->db->get('users');
    return $data->result(); // or  return $data->result_array();
    }
   }
?>
```

for result arrray you need to echo $object['id'];
and for result() same as you printing.